# C++ and file paths with national symbols (encoded with utf8, maybe)

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, filenames

I have some cross-platform code, and it's supposed to use some config file. All works fine, except case when config file name path contains non ANSI chars.

For opening/reading  file,  I'm using  `std::ifstream`. 
On windows platform (MSVC), solution is to use overloaded version of `std::ifstream`, which can accept path name as  `wchar_t*`, so path name encoded as utf16, and no problem with national symbols in path.

But what solution for NIX* systems ? 
From my knowledge all such files names encoded with UTF-8, and it's ok to use `char*` as pointer to string.
For example:

```
std::string path_name = ...; //assigning path name
std::ifstream fin(path_name.c_str());
```

But how about `c_str()` which return constant pointer to file name string, followed by `null` terminator ? Because UTF-8 bytes sequence can contain zeroes as part of code points, such string can be truncated.

So please direct me, where I'm wrong or please suggest some portable solution in case of I'm ok ))

Thank you.

Comment: ifstream has a constructor that takes a std::string as a parameter - no need to use c_str().

Comment: UTF-8 does not contain zeroes as part of code points. UTF-8 text is zero-terminated like ASCII text.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with "*All works fine, except case when config file name path contains non ANSI chars*" ? And what makes you think that the problem is the filename string ?

Comment: @ÖöTiib UTF-8 supposed to use up to four bytes, per symbol. Each bytes of multi-byte sequence  contains most significant bit  as 1. So , yes, you absolutely right - where is no zero byte on such utf-8 raw string.  This is what I was wrong about. Thank you. How I can mark your comment as answer ?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Shame on me. I'm  stuck on C++98 ) Starting from C++11 where is 'std::string' version of constructor  of  std::ifstream.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @user1503944 `UTF-8 supposed to use up to four bytes, per symbol.` Not *symbol*. You're probably thinking of *code point*. A symbol can consist of one or more code points (each of which consist of up to four code units in UTF-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 does not contain zeroes as part of code units. The bytes in multi-byte sequences must have most significant bit set. So UTF-8 text can be zero-terminated like ASCII text.

Therefore you can use `path_name.c_str()` as file name in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The bytes in a UTF-8 string are known as **Code Units**. **Code Points** are the Unicode values that UTFs encode into **code units**. In any case, there is a zero byte in UTF-8 - the `NUL` character, Unicode code point `U+0000`, which is encoded in UTF-8 as byte `0x00`, and thus can be used as a null terminator in a null-terminated string.